# select an object's class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-mapping

trying to create an object from an HQL query, but just can't figure out what i'm doing wrong: (Spring 3.1.1) How can I return a Java class, or at least the class or entity?

```
public Employee findEmployeeById(int id){

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM schema.Employee WHERE ID = ?";
    Employee employee = (Employee)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
            sql, new Object[] { id },new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Employee.class));

    return employee;

}
```

Employee.java

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="schema.Employee")
    public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private Department department;

    // Accessors

    }
```

Department.Java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="schema.DEPARTMENT")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private Long departmentId;

    @Column(name="DEPT_NAME")
    private String departmentName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
    private Set<employee> employees;

    // Getter and Setter methods
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your code? Any exceptions?

Comment: You're using a JdbcTemplate and a SQL query, to load a JPA entity? Your description says you're tryin to create an object from a HQL query. That's SQL, not HQL. And a HQL query is executed using the JPA ENtityManager os the Hibernate Session, not using JdbcTemplate.

Comment: @JB Nizet. Thanks for your hint. I am totally new in JPA and Hibernate..and you helped me to see the right direction.  But I still have a question if this would work if the name of Oracle table is like this "@Table(name="schema.Employee")" not like "@Table(name="Employee")" ?

Comment: HQL uses entity names. Not table names.